# Bluetooth Low Energy and GATT - Moto 360 Raw Sensor Data

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola, gatt

I'm developing an app on my android phone, which will sync data with wearable (moto 360). My problem is, that after connect and find device by method **getBondedDevices()** from **BluetoothAdapter** class, I can't find service with accelerometer data of my wearable. My **ParcelUuid** list have only 5 GATT services. It is possible to get and sync raw sensor data from wearable by bluetooth? Maybe SPP will be an answer for these question?

Regards.